# Emacs 26.3: changing the definition of "a word" when deleting words, moving by the word, etc

Tags: emacs

I'd like commands like alt-backspace, alt-B, alt-F etc. treat ranges of at least maybe 4 spaces as a word, or perhaps if it's a range of whitespace that includes a newline...

Any pointers for making such a modification?

Perhaps a simpler request: add underscore to set of characters recognized as a word, as C++ symbols often have underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `subword-mode` enabled, you can change the syntax of the characters you want to jump over, eg. `_` by wrapping any command you want in `with-syntax-table`, here wrapping `forward-word`,

```
(defvar my-syntax-table
  (let ((tab (copy-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" tab)
    tab))

(define-advice forward-word (:around (fn &rest args) "modified-syntax")
  (let (inhibit-field-text-motion)
   (with-syntax-table my-syntax-table
     (apply fn args))))
```

With `subword-mode`, it looks like you could modify the `subword-forward-regexp` and `subword-backward-regexp` variables to include the additional characters, eg. four spaces could be an addition of `" \\{4\\}"`.